# Compare two objects in Swift without casting to a specific type

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to compare two objects whose type is known at run time but not at compile time. So far I have the following function which seems to work as written:

```
/// Compares two objects of the given type.
/// Returns -1 if a is "less than" b, 1 if a is "greater than" b, 0 if they are equal, and nil if no comparison could be made.
func compare<T: Comparable>(type: T.Type,  a: Any?, b: Any?) -> Int? {
    guard let at = a as? T, let bt = b as? T else { return nil }
    return at < bt ? -1 : at > bt ? 1 : 0
}
```

The problem is, the type is not necessarily known to comply with the `Comparable` protocol at compile time; I really need to be able to pass in any type (`Any.Type`), not just `Comparable` ones. I'd then like the function to return `nil` if the passed-in type does not conform to `Comparable`. How can I do this?

**Edit (30/08/2018):** Some more context. I'm using this function to sort various arrays of strings, integers, and other `Comparable` types. However, because these arrays are retrieved via reflection the element types are not known at compile time. *I* know that they will always be `Comparable` but the compiler doesn't. To resolve this, I'm passing in the type as a separate parameter as shown. However, because I'd like to keep the logic as general as possible I'm performing this sort function inside a conditional statement which chooses the necessary type from an array. The type of this array must be `[Any.Type]` to hold the required types, even though all its contents conform to `Comparable` (`String.Type`, `Date.Type`, etc.).

Comment: Good question. (voted.) I experimented with it and couldn't get it to work either. I'm hoping somebody else does.

Comment: The best explanation I came up with “why things like this are not implemented” is, that Swift tries hard to be a static language and the feature you describe is dynamic. Static only because it is (supposedly) possible to optimize much more.